# problem while removing an element from the TreeSet

Tags: java, set

I am doing the following

```
class RuleObject implements Comparable{



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RuleObject [colIndex=" + colIndex + ", probability="
                + probability + ", rowIndex=" + rowIndex + ", rule=" + rule
                + "]";
    }
    String rule;
    double probability;
    int rowIndex;

    int colIndex;

    public RuleObject(String rule, double probability) {
        this.rule = rule;
        this.probability = probability;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        RuleObject ruleObj = (RuleObject)o;
        System.out.println(ruleObj);
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println(this);
        if(ruleObj.probability > probability)
            return 1;
        else if(ruleObj.probability < probability)
            return -1;
        else{
            if(ruleObj.colIndex == this.colIndex && ruleObj.rowIndex == this.rowIndex && ruleObj.probability == this.probability && ruleObj.rule.equals(this.rule))
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;

    }


}
```

And I have a TreeSet containing elements of RuleObject.
I am trying to do the following :

```
System.out.println(sortedHeap.size());
        RuleObject ruleObj = sortedHeap.first();
        sortedHeap.remove(ruleObj);
System.out.println(sortedHeap.size());
```

I can see that the size of set remains same. I am not able to understand why is it not being deleted. 
Also while deleting I could see compareTo method is called. But it is called for only 3 object whereas in set there are 8 objects.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the specification for [`remove`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Removes the specified element from this set if it is present. More formally, removes an element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`, if this set contains such an element.

Your problem is that `RuleObject` does not `@Override equals(Object other)`. You need to do that, and of course, with that you also need to `@Override hashCode()`.

---

Also, the reason why `compareTo` is being called fewer times than the number of elements is because it's supposed to be a `O(log N)` operation; that's the whole purpose of using `TreeSet`. If you have 1024 elements, you can expect `compareTo` to be called no more than 10 times.

---

As Vlad points out, your comparator is broken. Specifically, the last statement `return 1;` breaks it. You should expand the equal `probability` case to return -1, 0, +1 depending on the other fields.

Comment: i had implemented the hashcode and equals method but it didnt work because to my understanding is that in Treeset the compareTo method will be used to find whether object are equal or not

Comment: That's not what the documentation is saying, now, is it?

Comment: if i return 0 , then two different objects will be equals and it wont be added to set.

Comment: i was using the wrong data structure , now using priority queue

Comment: @harshit, OK, but even with `PriorityQueue` your `compareTo` has to define a total order, although with `PriorityQueue` you have the luxury of comparing `priority` only if you want (and not care about `rowIndex` or `colIndex`); `compareTo()` must **ALWAYS** satisfy `a.compareTo(b) == -b.compareTo(a)`

Comment: yes , copmpareTo was working fine earlier as set was sorted. only problem i was getting in removing the element. but with queue i can simply peek and remove it . so somehow its working :) thanks @Vlad for the help

Answer (score 4):

As `polygenelubricants` indicated, you must implement `equals` on your `RuleObject`s.

Moreover, your [comparator](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is essentially broken.  It does not impose [total ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), i.e. in certain cases it will claim that a `RuleObject` `a` is both greater than and less than another `RuleObject` `b` (e.g. if `a.probability`==`b.probability` and `a.colIndex` != `b.colIndex`.)  This will result in unwanted behaviour during tree insertion, traversal etc.

In the end, [`compareTo` must also be consistent with `equals`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), i.e.

> The natural ordering for a class C is
>   said to be consistent with equals if
>   and only if (e1.compareTo((Object)e2)
>   == 0) has the same boolean value as e1.equals((Object)e2) for every e1 and
>   e2 of class C. Note that null is not
>   an instance of any class, and
>   e.compareTo(null) should throw a
>   NullPointerException even though
>   e.equals(null) returns false.

If you do not care about `RuleObject`s ordering, use a `HashSet`.

Otherwise (i.e. you want to iterate over the `TreeSet` in a well defined, e.g. priority, order), implement `Comparable` to take into account all fields of interest, e.g.:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
  RuleObject r = (RuleObject)o;
  // assume no nulls for now, but you should eventually check
  // also assume o is always of type RuleObject for now,
  //  but you should eventually check
  return
    priority < r.priority ? -1 :
    priority > r.priority ? 1 :
    colIndex < r.colIndex ? -1 :
    colIndex > r.colIndex ? 1 :
    rowIndex < r.rowIndex ? -1 :
    rowIndex > r.rowIndex ? 1 : 0;
}

boolean equals(Object o) {
  // Delegate to compareTo(); no code duplication, consistent.
  return compareTo(o) == 0;
}
```

Comment: i got it what you are saying . then probably set is not a good way to implement it.

Comment: unless you need to order your `RuleObject`s I would use a `HashSet`.  If you do need to order them then take into account all members (e.g. `rowIndex`, `colIndex`, ...) not only when they are all equal but also when they are not.

Comment: Even ignoring that, the `compareTo` is backwards.  It returns positive when `this` is less than  `o`, and negative when it's greater.  That's the opposite of the spec.

Comment: @Matt, that's not necessarily "a bad thing", if he wants to reverse ordering then he can return 1 when `this` < `o`. :)  Not sure whether that's what he really wants or not, but he'll find out soon enough.  Everything should work fine except for elements being traversed in reverse order when/if he iterates over them.

Comment: Yes, clearly he could want the order opposite to the member fields` "natural" order.  But given the other issues, I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to Just Work™, try Apache's [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html), [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html), and [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html).  I have provided sample code to start from below.  You certainly don't have to take this route, but I think you will find it simplifies things.  Note the consistent pattern between the different functions.

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
  RuleObject ruleObj = (RuleObject) o;
  return new CompareToBuilder()
    .append(this.probability, ruleObj.probability)
    .append(this.colIndex, ruleObj.colIndex)
    .append(this.rowIndex, ruleObj.rowIndex)
    .append(this.rule, ruleObj.rule)
    .toComparison();
}

public int hashCode() {
  // You should customize the hard-coded numbers, as described in the docs.
  return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
    append(probability).
    append(colIndex).
    append(rowIndex).
    append(rule).
    toHashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) { return false; }
  if (obj == this) { return true; }
  if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
    return false;
  }
  RuleObject rhs = (RuleObject) obj;
  return new EqualsBuilder()
    .append(probability, rhs.probability)
    .append(colIndex, rhs.colIndex)
    .append(colIndex, rhs.colIndex)
    .append(rule, rhs.rule)
    .isEquals();
}
```